# cumulative sum using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
  select configurationfromintarray(1,string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[]) as config, 
        p.partname,rtrim(sum(distinct a.ref || ','),',') as refs,
        p.partid as partid,
        from productiongeneratebom(string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[],2405) a 
        join .....
        group by configurationfromintarray(1,string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[]),
        p.partname,p.partid
```

Which gives the following result:

```
config  partname  refs           partid
SBC1    test1   C250,C252        7102
SBC1    test2   C344,C419,C421   1034  
SBC2    test45  C111             3986
```

The query runs with in a function and the info parameters changes accordingly.
Basically it means that for configuration `SBC1` I'll need to place part `test1` in refs `C250,C252`. What I don't know is the quantity required to be placed. So I need to add a column which shows that information.

The FROM cluster has another column called `quantity`.

If I do

```
select ref,partid,quantity
from productiongeneratebom(string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[],2405) a
where partid=7102 order by ref
```

I'll get:

```
ref partid quanity
C250  7102   1
C252  7102  3
```

I want to modify my query to also have a column with the total quantity needed.
So in the above example it will be:

```
config  partname  refs           partid    QUANTITY
SBC1    test1   C250,C252        7102         4     // 3 from C250, 1 from C252
SBC1    test2   C344,C419,C421   1034         ?
SBC2    test45  C111             3986         ?
```

I tried to do it with :
`sum(a.quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY  rtrim(sum(distinct a.ref || ','),',')) AS quantity` but it doesn't work. it says:

> ERROR:  column "a.quantity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

How can I fix it? This summing should be difficult to implement.

**EDIT:**
If I remove the distinct word from

```
p.partname,rtrim(sum(distinct a.ref || ','),',') as refs,
```

I will get:

```
config  partname  refs           partid    
SBC1    test1   C250,C252,C252,C252,C252,C250,C250,C250       7102
```

The `distinct` make sure that I will see each ref only once. However I can't use the `distinct` key word for the summing of quantity so If I simply add:
sum (a.quantity) I will get incorrect result.

```
config  partname  refs                                        partid quantity
SBC1    test1   C250,C252,C252,C252,C252,C250,C250,C250       7102     16
```

I need it to sum the quantity of each ref only once!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a simple `sum(quantity)`:

```
select configurationfromintarray(1,string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[]) as config, 
        p.partname, rtrim(sum(distinct a.ref || ','),',') as refs,
        p.partid as partid,
        sum(quantity)
from productiongeneratebom(string_to_array('4441,4945',',')::int[],2405) a join .....
group by config, p.partname, p.partid;
```

You would use a window function if you wanted to combine values from multiple rows.

Comment: I tried that. it won't work. This is why there is a distinct when I create the ref string. The joins multiply the rows... I need a way to sum each ref quantity per the grouping only once.

Comment: @avi . . . You would seem to need two levels of aggregation, one at the ref level and then one to bring them together.

Comment: But how do I do that?